# "Er" added to name of sport, to refer to a player

Tags: grammar

When creating the designation for a person who plays a particular sport, I usually add *er* to the name of the sport. Some examples are *footballer*, *basketballer*, and *skateboarder*. Is this acceptable?

Comment: I think that that's less common in the United States, but quite common elsewhere (in the U.K. for instance).

Comment: True. My main problem is with basketballer. It just doesn't sound right although they can be referred to sometimes as 'baller'.

Comment: In the United States, basketballer would sound at least a little odd to most people, but still understandabble. On the other hand baller, wouldn't be seen to refer to basketball at all. Baller refers to someone living a big-time lifestyle: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=baller

Comment: I do it too.  I'm British, fwiw. ;)

Comment: I guess `cricketer` is more frequently used these days, but `cricketeer` was more usual in India when I was but a lad in pads.

Comment: Skee-Lo, is an American rapper: [baller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryDOy3AosBw) must be referring to basketball more than "living a big time lifestyle"

Comment: I suspect adding -_er_ works mainly for hobbies or more modern sports: _surfer_, _skateboarder_, _snowboarder_, _skier_ .  Older/mainstream sports such as basketball, hockey, tennis should not take an -_er_ ending.  I think _footballer_ is popularized British slang (but not proper), and perhaps _runner_ / _swimmer_ mentally imply _racer_ ?

Answer (score 3):

And now for a bit of the US perspective.

*Footballer* is absolutely nonexistent here. Whether that has anything to do with the fact that we are referring to a different sport (American/Canadian style football as opposed to the world's football that we call soccer), I have no idea.

*Basketballer*, *baseballer*, and *hockeyer* are not used here, either. The last sounds particularly absurd, but I am including it on my way towards making a point, which is this: It appears to me that forming the noun to designate a participant in a sport by adding *-er* is generally valid for the individualized sporting function, but not if you are trying to derive the noun from the name of the sport itself. This is a generalization that of course cannot hold in all cases, especially because there is overlap between the names of sports and the individualized names of the activities they encompass, but as a general rule, it works fairly well.

For example, within the sport of baseball, whereas *baseballer* does not work, *pitcher*, *catcher*, *fielder* and some others do.

Addendum:
I've taken notice that the sports in which the *-er* ending is more likely to work are not merely those in which the name of the sport more or less overlaps the name of the activity, but are more particularly those characterized by being individual sports, rather than team sports. A golfer plays golf, a runner runs, archery is performed by an archer, and as our friend icy points out above, a skier skis, a surfer surfs, and so on. In team sports, players often have distinct positions with distinct functions and names. Perhaps in football/soccer, *footballer* is more acceptable because the division of labor between positions is not quite as distinct as in some other sports, whereas in American/Canadian football it is.

Again, exceptions can always be found. Tennis, for example. No one would ever call a person who plays tennis a tenniser, although it is kind of a nifty word, isn't it? :)

Comment: and within soccer -- _striker_, _defender_, _keeper_

Answer (score 2):

*Basketballer* sounds odd to my British ears, but then it's [quite recent, particularly in British literature](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=basketballer%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbasketballer%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and [almost completely eclipsed by *basketball player*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=basketballer%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbasketballer%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cbasketball+player%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbasketball+player%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Many sports definitely do form the players' name by adding *-er:* footballer; swimmer; shooter; archer; runner; jumper; diver; thrower. Others don't: basketballers don't appear very often, nor do javelinners.

I would surmise that where the root of the word is an old word (like *run* [Early Old English], *swim* [Old English], or *jump* [16th century]) and probably therefore monosyllabic, *-er* is the normal form of the participant. *Football* is neither old nor a monosyllable, but it **is** very commonly used and likely to form an *-er* player. It would appear *basketballer* is just beginning to gain currency in the same way.

Comment: N.B.: Google does not even know the ngram "soccerer".

Comment: *Soccer* is a very recent term like *football*, and not nearly in such common usage. Nor is it a monosyllable.